# Catboost: smaller installation possible?

Tags: catboost

is there a way to do a partial installation of CatBoost with a smaller footprint? The version of catboost I have takes up 161MB and I am trying to see if I can cut the size down.

For XGB I could install with no binaries (and no gpu support) by running "python -m pip install --no-binary xgboost xgboost", and this cuts down the size of XGB from 400MB down to 10MB. Is there something similar for CatBoost?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, they have a C++ header-only prediction-only version which I guess is the smallest it can possibly get for serving purposes:
https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/CatboostModelAPI.md

If you are only concerned about serving, then it's also possible to export a model to a format such as ONNX and read it with a different library, without having catboost installed.

If you want a small catboost library that could be used also for training, then you're probably out of luck.